# Estimating integral $\int\limits_{C}\frac{z^3}{z^2-1}\text{d}z$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Using the estimation lemma show that $$\left|\int\limits_C \frac{z^3}{z^2-1}\text{d}z\right|\le \frac{9}{8}\pi$$ where $C:\{z:|z|=3,\Re(z)\ge 0\}$.

The length of $C$ is $\pi$ and $\displaystyle \max_{z\in C}\left|\frac{z^3}{z^2-1}\right|\le\frac{3^3}{3^2-1}=\frac{27}{8}$, hence one get by estimation lemma that $$\left|\int\limits_{C}\frac{z^3}{z^2-1}\text{d}z\right|\le\frac{27}{8}\pi$$How can we show the required bound?

Comment: length of $C$ is $3\pi$ @Galc127

Comment: @Boris, can you explain? I understand that I need to divide by 3 if this is the case.

Comment: the length of path $l(\Gamma)$ of integration is $\frac{1}{2}$ of the circumfrence of the circle.

Comment: @Boris, you are right, but then I get even bigger bound...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$
\int_C z dz=\left[\frac{z^2}{2}\right]_{-3i}^{3i}=0,$$
we have \begin{align}
\int_C \frac{z^3}{z^2-1}dz&=\int_C \left(z+\frac{z}{z^2-1}\right)dz\\
&=\int_C \frac{z}{z^2-1}dz.\end{align}
Using the estimation lemma we have$$
\left| \int_C \frac{z}{z^2-1}dz\right|\le \int_C \frac{\,3\,}{8}|dz|=\frac{\,9\,}{8}\pi,$$
which implies $$
\left|\int_C \frac{z^3}{z^2-1}dz\right|\le \frac{\,9\,}{8}\pi.$$

Comment: but the maximum value of $\left|\int\limits_C \frac{z^3}{z^2-1}\text{d}z\right|=3.375$ over $C$ @ts375_zk26

Comment: @Boris    
Straight use of the estimation lemma
$$\left|\int_C \frac{z^3}{z^2-1}dz\right|\le ML,$$
where $M=\max_{z\in C} |\frac{z^3}{z^2-1}| $ and $L=l(C)$, leads to a bad eatimation $$
\left|\int_C \frac{z^3}{z^2-1}dz\right|\le \frac{27}{8}\cdot 3\pi.$$
We could not get $\frac{9}{8}\pi$. Replace $z^3$ by $z$ !