# finding maximum value of a complex function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

the maximum value of the function $$f(z)=\frac{z^3}{z^2-1}$$ along the countour $z\in \Gamma ,|z|=3 $
i thought it by this way that the maximum value of $z$ would be lying on the $|z|=3$ then it can be said that 
$$f(3e^{i\theta})=\frac{27e^{i3\theta}}{9e^{i2\theta }-1 }$$
we can say that we have to find the value of $\theta$ for which $f(z)$ is maximum so to find maximum value 
$$f'(3e^{i\theta})=0$$
$$27e^{i 3\theta}(3\theta)(9e^{i2\theta}-1)=27e^{i 3\theta}(18\theta e^{i\theta2})$$
$$e^{i2\theta}=\frac{1}{3}$$
Is  this a a way to find the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ on the $\Gamma$

this question arised from the question asked by the @Galc127

Comment: what does maximum means when it's a complex expression. you can maximize real functions and inequality is meaningless in complex case

Comment: Do you mean the max of $|f(z)|$?

Comment: If by "maximum", you mean the maximum of $|f(\theta)|$ for some *real* variable $\theta$, then yes. Standard Calculus techiques apply. Otherwise, it makes no sense.

Comment: yes the maximum value of $|f(z)|$

Comment: I haven't checked your calculations for typos, but yes in that case it's correct, because you have $g(\theta)=|f(\theta)|\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R_0^+}$ and this defaults to a real case in standard Calculus.

Comment: $|f(z)|=27\frac{1}{6\sqrt 3}$ is it right result because the right answer is $\frac{3}{8}$ @YiannisGalidakis

Comment: It's $\frac{27}{8}$. Not $\frac{3}{8}$. See answers below.

Comment: but what is wrong in this ,i had this doubt while solving this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718820/estimating-integral-int-limits-c-fracz3z2-1-textdz @YiannisGalidakis

Comment: Different question, different result. On the one you quote, the estimate is for the integral and at half turn. This one is for the *integrand* and for a full turn.

Comment: @Boris: If any of the answers below were helpful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) them. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: i highly appreciate your effort @yiannis galidakis Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Responding to your last comment:

It's a bit tricky. I used Maple for some of the intermediate calculations, but you can certainly go through it by hand.

If your complex function is:

$$f(z)=\frac{z^3}{z^2-1}$$

then, parametrizing it for the circle $\Gamma=\{z\colon |z|=3\}$, you get:

$$f(3\cdot e^{i\theta})=\frac{27\cdot e^{3i\theta}}{9\cdot e^{2i\theta}-1}$$

Now set $g\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$, with:

$$g(\theta)=f(3\cdot e^{i\theta})$$

And now you can use the following trick:

$$|g(\theta)|=\sqrt{\Re(g(\theta))^2+\Im(g(\theta))^2}$$

Wlog you can drop the square root (when minimaxing distances), so it suffices to solve the equation:

$$\frac{d|g(\theta)|^2}{d\theta}=0$$

which reduces to solving, after many tedious calculations:

$$-\frac{6561}{2}\cdot\frac{\cos(\theta)\cdot\sin(\theta)}{81\cdot\cos(\theta)^4-450\cdot\cos(\theta)^2+625}=0$$

which, by inspection, has immediately the roots:

$$\theta_1=0$$

$$\theta_2=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Here's the plot of $|g(\theta)|$:

[image]

And now you can verify that the corresponding extrema, are:

$$|g(0)|\doteq 3.375$$

and:

$$|g(\pi/2)|\doteq 2.7$$

Answer (score 0):

For a faster computation, note that on $\Gamma$ you have $|z^3|=3^3=27$ and hence
$$\left| f(z) \right|= \frac{27}{|z^2-1|} \mbox{ on } \Gamma$$

Also, by the triangle inequality you have
$$|z^2-1| \geq |z^2| -1 =9-1=8 \mbox{ on } \Gamma$$
with equality when $z^2=9$. This shows that 
$$|f(z)|  = \frac{27}{|z^2-1|} \leq  \frac{27}{8} \mbox{ on } \Gamma$$
with equality when $z^2=9$.