# Hessian Matrix Special Case

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, determinant

I'm currently reaching the end of my calculus 2 class and even though I understand how to use the Hessian Matrix and understand its results, I was left wondering, without an answer from my professor, what happened in the special case when the Hessian Matrix gave a positive result while fxx was equal to zero.

On my own I realized that this could only happen with complex or imaginary numbers as with most equations the Hessian matrix ends up being symetrical and as such if fxx was equal to zero, the determinant should be negative with all the real numbers. But with complex ones the case described above could happen and even though I supose that it's not critical for my present studies, I would still like to know what this meant.

As an extra, I would like to state that even though I have some basic to medium understanding of complex numbers, such as that they have both a real and imaginary part and are usually graphed on a plane, I wouldn't really know what a minimum or maximum would look like in the complex plane.

Any type of answer is appreciated and thanks in advance!

The simplest example I can think of would be the function:
$$f(x,y)=x*y^2$$
Which would create the Hessian Matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2y \\
2y & 2x \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The determinant of this matrix would then be equal to:
$$H(x,y)=-4y^2$$
And if one evaluates this function in $(x,i)$, one would get a positive result, in this case 4, though this i could be replaced for any multiple of it.
And in all of these cases $fxx$ would be equal to zero, meaning that the usual analysis of the Hessian matrix wouldn't work.

_

Update:

I have researched a bit more about the topic of maximizing complex functions and found out on the following post made on this same website: [finding maximum value of a complex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719057/finding-maximum-value-of-a-complex-function) and even though I don't completely understand what is being explained there, I managed to get that one uses the typical calculus method - evaluating the first derivative so that it's equal to zero.

Therefore, with many variables, I imagine that with complex numbers a similar analysis as with the real ones could be made. Perhaps this can help guide this question to an answer that I've yet to reach.

_

Second Update:

I managed to get into contact with another profesor and when I asked him this question he told me a few things and even though I didn't completely understand everything, my curiosity has been satisfied.

First of all, maximizing or minimizing a complex function means finding the largest or smallest vector because complex numbers are made of both a real and imaginary part.

Secondly, the analysis of the Hessian Matrix doesn't make much sense with complex functions or, at least, they are too advanced for a first-year engineering student to understand. And even so, the case described in the question, with a positively defined Hessian Matrix and a second derivative respect the first variable equal to zero has no special meaning.

Lastly, the thing that I comprehended the least, but something about second derivatives of complex functions using real numbers. This was the thing I understood the least so even though my personal curiosity has been satisfied, perhaps someone else has more details about this problem which they can also answer.

Comment: you really should give an example or two.